# Elements of $n$-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $\varepsilon_{1},...\varepsilon_{q}$ be the orthonormal system of vectors. Then we may represent elements $\xi_{q}$ on $n$-dimensional unit sphere $\Omega_{q}$ by the following linear combination

\begin{equation}
\xi_{q} = t\varepsilon_{q} + (1 - t^2)^{1/2}\xi_{q-1}, \hspace{0.1cm} -1\le t \le 1,\hspace{0.1cm} t = \varepsilon_{q} . \xi_{q} \hspace{2cm}       (1)
\end{equation}

where $\xi_{q-1}$ is a unit vector in the space spanned by $\varepsilon_{1},...\varepsilon_{n}.$

I don't see, how we can conclude formula (1) (formula is from the book Spherical Harmonics by Claus Muller).

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: Your indices are very confusing, please try to clarify them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index for $t$ in your equation, which would probably make it more clear:
$$\xi_{k} = t_k\varepsilon_{k} + (1 - t_k^2)^{1/2}\xi_{k-1}, \hspace{0.1cm} -1\le t_k \le 1 \hspace{2cm}       (1)$$
Also let's define $\xi := \xi_q$, just so we know which is the vector we are looking at.

If you were to expand this recursive formula, you would get that:
$$\xi_{q} = t_q\varepsilon_{q} + (1 - t_q^2)^{1/2} \xi_{q-1} = t_q\varepsilon_{q} + (1 - t_q^2)^{1/2}\left( t_{q-1}\varepsilon_{q-1} + (1 - t_{q-1}^2)^{1/2} \xi_{q-2} \right) = ... $$
$$\xi_{q} = \sum_{k=0}^{q} \varepsilon_{k} \left(t_k\prod_{m=0}^{k-1} \sqrt{1-t_m^2}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{q} p_k \varepsilon_{k}$$
, where $\sum_{k=0}^q p_k^2 = 1$. One other thing to note is that
$$\langle \xi, \varepsilon_k \rangle = p_k$$
because of the orthogonality of $\{\varepsilon_k\}$

Comment: Thanks. You have a point, but my main confusion is, why author used exactly coefficients $t$ and $(1 - t^2)^{1/2}.$ I mean, what is the reasoning for.

Comment: He only did this step for the first  dimension. I'm not sure what is the purpose there.